# Targeting two instances of key-value pair in specific indices of nested array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

Say I have a nested array something like

```js
var allPairs = [
  [
    { x: 1, y: 0 },
    { x: 1, y: 1 },
  ],
  [
    { x: 1, y: 1 },
    { x: 1, y: 2 },
  ],
  [
    { x: 1, y: 2 },
    { x: 2, y: 2 },
  ],
]
```

and I have an object

```js
var currentPair = {x: 1, y: 1};
```

I've been struggling with trying to find a way to check if, in `allPairs`, `currentPair` equals the second index [1] of one nested array, while also equaling the first index [0] of another nested array.

I've been playing around with `some`:

```
if (arrOfPointsUsed.some(e => e[1] === firstPoint)) {
    pointsFound++;
}
if (arrOfPointsUsed.some(e => e[0] === firstPoint)) {
    pointsFound++;
}
if (pointsFound > 1) {
    return false;
}
```

I've tried nested for loops also.

What is the best approach?

Comment: *"...equals the second index [1] of one nested array, while also equaling the first index [1]..."* Should one of those 1s be a 0 or a 2?

Comment: You're using `===` to compare objects. Is the object in `allPairs` really the **same object** as `firstPoint`? Or just an equivalent object?

Comment: yes, good call (regarding first comment).

and they are not really the same object, so `===` is definitely problematic.

Comment: You're probably looking for `Array#findIndex`: https://jsfiddle.net/dw30ah46/

Comment: "What is the best approach?" - what does "best" mean? performance? code readability? ... ? :-)

Comment: I mean performance, @JanStránský

Comment: Please in this kind of questions, try to include also expected output

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track with `some`, but I think you'll need two calls to it:

```
const foundBoth =
  // Found 0?
  allPairs.some(([{x, y}]) => x === currentPair.x && y == currentPair.y)
  &&
  // Found 1?
  allPairs.some(([, {x, y}]) => x === currentPair.x && y == currentPair.y)
;
```

Live Example:

```js
var allPairs = [ [{x: 1, y: 0}, {x: 1, y: 1}], [{x: 1, y: 1}, {x: 1, y: 2}], [{x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 2, y: 2} ] ];

var currentPair = {x: 1, y: 1};

const foundBoth =
  // Found 0?
  allPairs.some(([{x, y}]) => x === currentPair.x && y == currentPair.y)
  &&
  // Found 1?
  allPairs.some(([, {x, y}]) => x === currentPair.x && y == currentPair.y)
;

console.log(foundBoth);
```

Or to do it in one pass, you could use a loop:

```
let foundBoth = false;
let found0 = false;
let found1 = false;
for (const [e0, e1] of allPairs) {
    found0 = found0 || e0.x === currentPair.x && e0.y === currentPair.y;
    found1 = found1 || e1.x === currentPair.x && e1.y === currentPair.y;
    foundBoth = found0 && found1;
    if (foundBoth) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
var allPairs = [ [{x: 1, y: 0}, {x: 1, y: 1}], [{x: 1, y: 1}, {x: 1, y: 2}], [{x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 2, y: 2} ] ];

var currentPair = {x: 1, y: 1};

let foundBoth = false;
let found0 = false;
let found1 = false;
for (const [e0, e1] of allPairs) {
    found0 = found0 || e0.x === currentPair.x && e0.y === currentPair.y;
    found1 = found1 || e1.x === currentPair.x && e1.y === currentPair.y;
    foundBoth = found0 && found1;
    if (foundBoth) {
        break;
    }
}

console.log(foundBoth);
```

...but `allPairs` would have to be ***massive*** for making one pass vs. two to make a difference.

---

Some notes on the above:

1. I've assumed that the `currentPair` object and the matching objects in `allPairs` are merely *equivalent*, not the same object. That's why I'm checking `x` and `y`, not `===` on the object themselves. (Because two separate objects are never `===` one another.)
2. I'm using destructuring in various places, both iterable destructuring to pick out the 0th and 1st entries from each of the subarrays and object destructuring to pick out the `x` and `y` properties of those objects. In the first example (using `some`), `[{x, y}]` in the first `some` call's callback function's parameter list picks the `x` and `y` properties out of the first entry in the subarray, and `[,{x, y}]` does the same for the second (skipping the first entry with the `,` at the beginning).
3. If it were even **one tiny bit** more complex to compare the objects than just the `x` and `y` checks above, I'd factor that comparison operation out into its own function and reuse it.

---

In a comment you've asked:

> Thanks for your thorough answer. Just trying to understand your syntax in the first example: how would I, for instance, find if the first index is equivalent to currentPair in more than one array within allPairs

For that I'd probably use `find` or `findIndex` twice: The first time to find the first index, the second time to find another one that isn't the first one. For instance:

```
const firstIndex = allpairs.findIndex(([{x, y}]) => x === currentPair.x && y == currentPair.y);
const secondIndex = firstIndex === -1 ? -1 : allpairs.findIndex(([{x, y}], index) => index > firstIndex && x === currentPair.x && y == currentPair.y);
if (secondIndex !== -1) {
  // Found in the first entry of two different subarrays
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. Just trying to understand your syntax in the first example: how would I, for instance, find if the first index is equivalent to `currentPair` in more than one subarray within `allPairs`?

Comment: @icartus - I've added to the end to do an example of that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the values instead of the object reference.

For the check, you need the entries of the target object and iterate this as well.

```js
const
    allPairs = [[{ x: 1, y: 0 }, { x: 1, y: 1 }], [{ x: 1, y: 1 }, { x: 1, y: 2 }], [{ x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 2, y: 2 }]],
    currentPair = { x: 1, y: 1 },
    entries = Object.entries(currentPair),
    result = allPairs.some(array => 
        array.some(object =>
            entries.every(([key, value]) => object[key] === value)
        )
    );

console.log(result);
```